# Cordova adds unnecessary permissions to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, permissions, manifest

While building an ionic project, I've noticed that AndroidManifest.xml is being generated each time I run :`cordova build --release android` and adds permissions I don't really need.

I've googled around and found the following markup to add to config.xml:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

However this does not work, and the AndroidManifest.xml file is generated each time with lot's of unnecessary permissions.

What it the right way to configure the app permissions?

**Update:**

Important note: I'm using [**this YEOMAN generator**](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic) for my project

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using some plugins. 
These plugins could add permissions so you'll have to check && edit/remove them. First have a look in /plugins/android.json. 
Also in /plugins/my_plugin/plugin.xml you can find exactly what permissions they request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I can't see plugins.xml or android.json in my project. It is probably because I use a custom generator (see my edits).

Comment: I use diegonetto's ionic-generator as well. On platform add it creates a /plugins folder in the root of your project (not in /app or /platforms). So after a platform:add and before the build:android you have to remove the unwanted permissons from the files as @Ungureanu explained.